# How do I move the two turtles in my program at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

When I run the program all is well in the sense that the player2 turtle bounces off the window as expected and when it collides with the player turtle(the user) it's position is set to a random location and stops going forward. However as the player2 turtle moves(the non user) and the player turtle moves at the same time both turtles freeze and are glitchy during the whole process.

```
import turtle
import random
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(width = 450, height = 450)
wn.bgcolor("green")
player = turtle.Turtle()
player2 = turtle.Turtle()
player.shape("square")
player2.shape("turtle")
player.penup()
player2.penup()
player.setpos(0,0)
player.showturtle()
player2.showturtle()
player2.setpos(150,150)
#the x and y distance that the player2 turtle moves in the main loop
dx = 5
dy = 5


def up():
    y = player.ycor()
    y = y + 5
    player.sety(y)

    if y>=310:
        player.sety(y-15)

def down():
    y = player.ycor()
    y = y - 5
    player.sety(y)
    if y<-310:
        player.sety(y+15)


def left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x = x - 5
    player.setx(x)
    if x<=-625:
        player.setx(x+15)


def right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x = x + 15
    player.setx(x)

    if x>=625:
        player.setx(x-15)



def checkcollision(t1,t2):
        if abs(t1.xcor() - t2.xcor()) < 10 and abs(t1.ycor() - t2.ycor()) < 10:
            pos = player.xcor()
            player2.fd(0)
            player2.setpos(random.randint(-250,250), random.randint(-250,250))
            if (pos) != player2.xcor():
                while True:
                    player2.fd(0)


#main loop
while True:

    wn.listen()
    wn.onkeypress(up,"Up")

    wn.onkeypress(left,"Left")

    wn.onkeypress(right,"Right")

    wn.onkeypress(down, "Down")

    x2 = player2.xcor()
    y2 = player2.ycor()
    player2.setx(x2 + dx)
    player2.sety(y2 + dy)

    head = player2.heading()

    checkcollision(player,player2)
    if y2>=300:
        player2.sety(300)
        dy *= -1
        player2.sety(y2 + dy)


    if y2<=-310:
        player2.sety(-310)
        dy *=-1
        player2.sety(y2 + dy)


    if x2<=-625:
        player2.setx(-625)
        dx *=-1
        player2.setx(x2 + dx)



    if x2>=625:
       player2.setx(625)
       dx  *=-1
       player2.setx(x2 + dx)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try again, but you ignored the [advice and code I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60612471/5771269) in my answer to your previous question about this same program.

First, your code doesn't seem to understand it's own coordinate system -- you defined the x coordinates as going from -225 to +225 but you're testing if the turtle's x coordinate is >= 625 and similar coordinate inconsistencies.

You have an infinite loop in your `checkcollision()` function:

```
while True:
    player2.fd(0)
```

There's no way out of that.  Turtle has a `distance()` method so you don't need to do:

```
abs(t1.xcor() - t2.xcor()) < 10 and abs(t1.ycor() - t2.ycor())
```

In an event-driven world like turtle, there shouldn't be a main loop of the form `while True:` -- use timer events instead.  Also doing `onkeypress()` and `listen()` in a loop doesn't make sense, they only need to be done once.

The `checkcollision()` function can change the position of `player2` so this sequence of commands is questionable:

```
y2 = player2.ycor()
...
checkcollision(player,player2)
if y2>=300:
```

As `y2` may no longer represent the y position of `player2` after the `checkcollision()` call.

Below is my rework to address your question, the above problems and other issues:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

def up():
    y = player.ycor() + 5

    if y >= 200:
        y -= 15

    player.sety(y)

def down():
    y = player.ycor() - 5

    if y < -200:
        y += 15

    player.sety(y)

def left():
    x = player.xcor() - 5

    if x <= -200:
        x += 15

    player.setx(x)

def right():
    x = player.xcor() + 5

    if x >= 200:
        x -= 15

    player.setx(x)

def checkcollision(t1, t2):
    while t1.distance(t2) < 10:
        t2.setpos(randint(-100, 100), randint(-100, 100))

# the x and y distance that the player2 turtle moves in the main loop
dx = 5
dy = 5

def move():
    global dx, dy

    checkcollision(player, player2)

    x2, y2 = player2.position()
    player2.setposition(x2 + dx, y2 + dy)

    if y2 <= -200 or y2 >= 200:
        dy *= -1
        player2.sety(y2 + dy)

    if x2 <= -200 or x2 >= 200:
        dx *= -1
        player2.setx(x2 + dx)

    screen.ontimer(move, 100)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=450, height=450)
screen.bgcolor('green')

player = Turtle()
player.shape('square')
player.penup()

player2 = Turtle()
player2.shape('turtle')
player2.penup()
player2.setpos(150, 150)

screen.onkeypress(up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(down, 'Down')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```